# Pentaho Marketplace Install Saiku Chart Plus Plugin Failed

Tags: plugins, pentaho, saiku

I currently have Pentaho 5.0.1-stable Bi server. I already installed:

Community Dashboards Framework, 
Community Data Access,Community Dashboard Editor,
Community Graphics Generator,
Saiku Analytics.

But I also need to install Saiku Chart Plus Plugin. But I cannot download it. 
Here is what the log says:
[image]

I noticed the errors says that the Plugin did not contain ID.

Please help on installing the plugin. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the downloaded ZIP file - it usually means that the Marketplace got some kind of redirect response and ZIP contains html file with an address to plugin.
When you download zipped plugin, extract it in /pentaho-solutions/system folder and restart the server